# Indexing subgroups by sorted positions in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains information about several categories, and some associated variables. It is of the form:

```
   ID       category     sales    score
   227          A         109       21
   131          A         410       24
   131          A         509        1
   123          B           2       61
   545          B          19        5
   234          C         439      328
   654          C         765       41
```

What I would like to do is be able to introduce two new columns, `salesRank` and `scoreRank`, where I find the item index per category, had they been ordered by `sales` and `score`, respectively. I can solve the general case like this:

```
dF <- dF[order(-dF$sales),]
dF$salesRank<-seq.int(nrow(dF))
```

but this doesn't account for the categories and so far I've only solved this by breaking up the dataframe. What I want would result in the following:

```
   ID       category    sales    score    salesRank    scoreRank
   227          A         109       21         3            2
   131          A         410       24         2            1
   131          A         509        1         1            3
   123          B           2       61         2            1
   545          B          19        5         1            2
   234          C         439      328         2            1
   654          C         765       41         1            2
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(salesRank = row_number(desc(sales)),
         scoreRank = row_number(desc(score)))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [7 x 6]
#Groups: category
# 
#   ID category sales score salesRank scoreRank
#1 227        A   109    21         3         2
#2 131        A   410    24         2         1
#3 131        A   509     1         1         3
#4 123        B     2    61         2         1
#5 545        B    19     5         1         2
#6 234        C   439   328         2         1
#7 654        C   765    41         1         2
```

From the help:

- `row_number()`: equivalent to `rank(ties.method = "first")`
- `min_rank()`: equivalent to `rank(ties.method = "min")`
- `desc()`: transform a vector into a format that will be sorted in descending
  order.

---

As @thelatemail pointed out, for this particular dataset you might want to use `min_rank()` instead of `row_number()` which will account for ties in sales/score more appropriately:

```
> row_number(c(1,2,2,4))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
> min_rank(c(1,2,2,4))
#[1] 1 2 2 4
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. As a follow-up question, is it possible to group by multiple categories? I will look into the documentation of dplyr to try and answer this myself too :)

Comment: Yes. you could do `group_by(ID, category)` for instance. See `?group_by`

Comment: You could also use `rank` which will account for ties in sales/score more appropriately.

Comment: @thelatemail `row_number` is equivalent to `rank(ties.method = "first")`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré - which seems inappropriate for this example sales data - e.g. `row_number(c(1,2,2,4))` returns `1,2,3,4`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ave` in base R with `rank` (the `-` is to reverse the rankings from low-to-high to high-to-low):

```
dF$salesRank <- with(dF, ave(-sales, category, FUN=rank) )
#[1] 3 2 1 2 1 2 1
dF$scoreRank <- with(dF, ave(-score, category, FUN=rank) )
#[1] 2 1 3 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: I'm curious if there's a reason to prefer this over `within(df,{
 salesRank = ave(-sales, category, FUN=rank);
 scoreRank = ave(-score, category, FUN=rank)
})` Seems like less typing.

Comment: @Frank - much of a muchness, you could do it all in one go for sure and `within` is quite neat. That would copy the whole dataframe though I think, which might be less efficient than just doing the column by column calculations. Which might copy the whole thing too... I dunno. Not my strong point.

Comment: @Frank , plus in `within`, you need to do `<-` not `=` - you could use `transform` with `=` though

Comment: Actually, I tried the code I ran, with `=` and it worked. I think anywhere `<-` works, `=` also works. The point about copying makes sense, though.

Comment: @Frank - interesting - `within(dF, a="a")` fails while `within(dF, {a = "a"})` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I have just a base R solution with `tapply`.

```
salesRank <- tapply(dat$sales, dat$category, order, decreasing = T)
scoreRank <- tapply(dat$score, dat$category, order, decreasing = T)

cbind(dat, salesRank = unlist(salesRank), scoreRank= unlist(scoreRank))

    ID category sales score salesRank scoreRank
A1 227        A   109    21         3         2
A2 131        A   410    24         2         1
A3 131        A   509     1         1         3
B1 123        B     2    61         2         1
B2 545        B    19     5         1         2
C1 234        C   439   328         2         1
C2 654        C   765    41         1         2
```

Comment: This depends on `dat` being sorted by `category`, right?

Comment: @Frank is right - `ave` is preferably to `unlist(tapply())` as `tapply` sorts the results. The original data needs to be sorted appropriately first.

Comment: `tapply` is the first functions I've thought, I am still new to R in fact, I am learning. @Frank I  do agree with you, thank you very much for your comment because at first glance I didn't think about the case of unsorted `category`.